# Dart: A value of type 'int' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'

Tags: dart, types, extension-methods

When I write an extension like so:

```dart
extension MyExtension<int> on List<int> {
  void myMethod() {
    int a = 1; // error
  }
}
```

I get a seemingly nonsensical error message from the compiler:

> A value of type 'int' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'.
> Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'int'. dart([invalid_assignment](https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages?utm_source=dartdev&utm_medium=redir&utm_id=diagcode&utm_content=invalid_assignment#invalid_assignment))

I can fix the problem by removing `<int>` after the extension name:

```dart
extension MyExtension on List<int> {
  void myMethod() {
    int a = 1;
  }
}
```

But I'd like to know what was going on in the original problematic code. What was the reason for the cryptic error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you are having a simple problem, you are reassigning the meaning of int

```
extension MyExtension<int> on List<int>
```

Your extension takes a type argument, which means that when using the extension, you can pass many different types to it, but the name of this new type argument is `int`.

So you are assigning an int (the number) to int (the type argument) which is impossible because dart does not know if int (the type argument) will be an int.

In order to fix this, you can remove the type argument as you did, the code you show does not need a type argument, you can also rename the type argument, the convention says type arguments should be called T:

```
extension MyExtension<T> on List<int> ...
```

if what you want is for the type argument to always be an int, or a class that extends int you can also declare that:

```
extension MyExtension<T extends int> on List<int> ...
```

If you still have trouble understanding what type arguments are and how they work, [here is the documentation for type arguments](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generics) and [here is the documentation for extensions with type arguments](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generics)